# Compare data using Conditional Formatting in same worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to highlight the columns (Role1, Role2, Role3) for every changes happened when I compare the rows based on the Date and UserName. In my example below, when I filter the date from May 2018, it will appear all the entries for that month. I need to compare the roles based from the UserName.

[image]

For example, I need to compare all the entries for username Handi, I need to check the date and time and compare it to the next day. In 1st entry dated **(5/14/2018 9:09:24.0)**, value of **Role1** is RO, **Role2** is N and **Role3** is 300000. In 2nd entry **(5/21/2018 19:09:24.0)**, value of **Role1** is RO, **Role2** is Y and **Role3** is 400000. If you noticed, there are changes happened in **Role2** and **Role3** and in this case, I need to highlight that Roles in Red. Then, the last entry **(5/31/2018 05:09:24.0)** I will compare it to the **(5/21/2018 19:09:24.0)**. Same process will do.

Can you give me an idea on how will I do that in excel using Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Is "Date" a cell formated as date?

Comment: No, need to customize the date format to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.0